# Get the full path of the matched file with egrep

Tags: linux

I'm using the below script to find matching words in specific paths:

```sh
for i in `ls |egrep -v 'dev|sys|mnt'`; do echo $(date); echo $i; egrep -rn "Word1|Word2|Word3" $i; done
```

it writes something like this:

```
Sun Jul 4 14:23:04 UTC 2021
hs_err_100125.log
```

How can i get the full path written for each result?

Comment: See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/3651) for why this is a bad idea, and how to do it better. In your case, you’d probably want to use `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do …; done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name \*dev\* -a -not -name \*sys\* -a -not -name \*mnt\* -print0)`. Yes, a lot more complicated. But correct (though untested).

Comment: Thanks - where should the Word1|Word2|Word3 be? Can you suggest a full edit of your solution?

Comment: The code in my comment already contains that part.

Answer (score 0):

You're working in your current directory. This is kept in the environment variable `PWD`. So, adding `$PWD"/"` in front of your result should do the trick.

Comment: where exactly should I add it ? ```for i in `ls |egrep -v 'dev|sys|mnt'`; do echo $(date); echo $i; egrep -rn "Word1|Word2|Word3" $i; done
```

Comment: I believe you should put it in front of `$i`, like `echo $PWD"/"$i`.

Comment: Thanks. it added the actual PWD. Is there a way to tell this script to run from "/" and not from "/root"?  I mean - One level up?

Comment: One level up is written as `..` or `../`.